# ng build fails with "export not found" errors within my code after update to v8

Tags: angular, build, angular8

After update from v7 to v8 ng build fails with several errors like that.

The curious thing is that this is entirely my code, that worked perfectly fine in v7. I can't find anything wrong with the code neither does the WebStorm indexer. How to troubleshoot such things?

I removed and reinstalled node_modules several times.

```js
ERROR in ./src/app/login/elevate-login-dialog/elevate-login-dialog.component.ts 17:16-32
"export 'UnauthorizedInfo' was not found in '../../shared/core/api/ahc-api'
```

edit: as requested the content of ahc.api.ts. I cannot share the entire file, but this is the relevant part:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AbsBackendService } from "./abs-backend.service";
import { ILogger } from "../../../../utils/logging/logger/logger.interface";

...

export interface UnauthorizedInfo {
        readonly TokenInvalid:boolean;
        readonly RequiredUserGroup?:UserGroup;
        readonly RequiredUserID?:number;
        readonly RequestedResource?:string;
        readonly RequestedRestMethod?:string;
      }

...
```

Comment: Share the ../../shared/core/api/ahc-api file.

Comment: edited the post

Comment: Try using the interface in a standalone file: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2034

Comment: That does indeed remove this specific error. But I don't see the logic behind it. Moreover the issue you linked is about interfaces in classes which produce warnings not errors.

Unfortunately there are lot more errors of that kind and putting each interface into it's own file would take forever and is not even possible atm due to our infrastructure. Moreover there are also framework source files affected. 

I don't understand the problem in the first place.

Comment: ok, looks like this issue might be relevant: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14876 thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: People in the post are downgrading to @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.800.3. It seems to be an issue with @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.800.4

Answer (score 0):

this is a regression bug introduced in angular-cli 8.0.4

a simple

`npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.800.3 @angular/cli@8.0.3`

"fixed" the issue on my code base